# Low performance in JBoss 5

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, ejb-2.x, jboss-4.2.x

I got a strange performance problem switching from JBoss 4 to JBoss 5. There is a stateless bean method and it is invoked in 44 sec in JBoss 4. It's OK. After I run that method in JBoss 5 it takes > 5 min and transaction timeout exception interrupts the flow.

What can be a reason of that performance problem in two versions of JBoss? Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not low JBoss 5 performance problem, but something goes completely wrong in this case.
Just make a [threaddump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787/how-do-you-generate-and-analyze-a-thread-dump-from-a-running-jboss-instance/5720826#5720826) and you'll see the reason.