# JBOSS Slow Response

Tags: java, jboss

I deployed a war in JBOSS in windows os and this is working fine, but when the same war I deployed in linux system, it is getting very slow ans takes around 3-4 minutes to process a request. What may be the reason?

Comment: Are you getting any logs? After 3-4 minutes is your application giving desired response or is it some errors?

Comment: This would help to find the reason of such enormous slowness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787/how-do-you-generate-and-analyze-a-thread-dump-from-a-running-jboss-instance/

Answer (score 2):

Will need more information to provide any suggestions at all. Is the code (war file) windows specific ? Is there any error in the log files ? What does cpu/memory/disk on the Linux server look like when you deploy the war file ? What is the heap size of the jvm on Linux vs Windows ?

Comment: There are no any errors in log file and this war is not windows specific as well. Heap size is 1303M. I am getting the desired result as well but it is too slow. This behaviour is observed when client code which is in a different physical Apache Http Server makes Ajax request to server code which is deployed in JBOSS which runs on another physical machine.

Comment: Sorry but i forgot to mention one thing that this issue is occurring when the request is sent from iPad, in case the request is sent from desktop pc it works fine. Client code is only for iPad.

Comment: What about the cpu, memory, disk usage on the jboss server ? Also, does jboss make a db call ? Are the db responses returning within  accepted time limits ?

Comment: Hi All, It was strange but true, restarted JBOSS and problem solved. Thanks:)

Comment: Hello Everyone Good Morning I am again facing the same issue, and each time i restart JBOSS it starts working fine. Any Suggesstions?

Comment: Suggestions are still the same :) Check cpu/memory/disk. Check log files. Check verbose gc logs (if you have them). If it connects to a db, check db connectivity.